# UICollectionViewCell Bad Access on NSMutableArray

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview, exc-bad-access, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a UICollectionView in an app where the cells of the collection view are based on data coming from a server.

When the app loads I download the data from the server and convert it into individual NSObjects which are stored in an NSMutableArray

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
```

The count of this dataArray is then used to determine the number of cells in the collection view.

The problem arises when I try and access this dataArray in the cellForItemAtIndexPath collection view delegate method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReminderCard" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    GMReminderCard *reminderCard = (GMReminderCard *)cell;
    GMReminder *rem = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [reminderCard initialiseReminder:rem];

    cell.layer.cornerRadius     = 5;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds    = YES;
    return cell;
}


- (void)initialiseReminder:(GMReminder *)rem
{
    if(!loan)return;

    _thisReminder = rem;


    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_thisReminder.image relativeToURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://host.cloudfront.net/"]];

    [self.image setImageWithURL:[imageURL absoluteURL]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"973-user.png"]];

    [_title setText:[_thisReminder title]];
    [_description setText:[_thisReminder description]];
}
```

Here is my code for fetching the data from the server, the NSMutableArray returned contains GMReminder objects:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [GMReminders getCurrentReminders:^(NSMutableArray *rems, NSError *err){
        if (!err) {
            dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:rems];
            [collectionView reloadData];
        }
    }];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self buildBackgroundSlider];
    [self buildLabel];
    [self buildCollectionView];
}
```

Initially the cells load as expected but when I attempt to scroll the collection view I get a bad access error thrown on the first attempt to use a GMReminder variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What does `initialiseReminder:` do?

Comment: I've added the initialiseReminder method

Answer (score 0):

In ViewDidload method make collectionview programmatically:-

```
UICollectionView *collection_view=[[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [collection_view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.810746 green:0.764681 blue:0.764681 alpha:0.8]];
    collection_view.delegate = self;
    collection_view.dataSource = self;
    [collection_view registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [self.view addSubview:collection_view];
```

Define Delegate for cell of UicollectionView:-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier=@"cellIdentifier";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,0,cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really help as building the cell is not the problem, it's initialising the data within the cell using the _dataArray that is crashing the app

Comment: plz try this in viewdidload  self.dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: I have initialised the array already in my code. Ill add the methods which fetch the data from the server in the original question

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:rems];
```

with

```
dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[rems copy]];
```